# List of GPO's for Windows Admins

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, windows-server-2008, active-directory, group-policy

I am hoping we can get a list together of usful/must use GPOs for Windows Admins.

Maybe explain how to set them up and why they are helpful?

Comment: I would say that this is a duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/66049/what-group-policies-have-you-applied

Comment: I would say you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=18c90c80-8b0a-4906-a4f5-ff24cc2030fb&displaylang=en

thanks,
mark

Answer (score 0):

why would you need to apply GPO's spefically to Domain admins? Your question is a bit vague, can you explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I was asking for a list of useful/common GPOs that Domain admins use on their domains, not on themselves.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many things that you can do with GPO's. There aren't any specific templates only best practice. Look up the threats and countermeasures guide on Microsoft.com